# How to create zip file using TrueZip?

Tags: java, truezip

The example on their website is

```
File entry = new TFile("archive.zip/dir/HälloWörld.txt");
Writer writer = new TFileWriter(entry);
try {
    writer.write("Hello world!\n");
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

In my use case, I have the following structure

```
log/a.log
log/b.log
log/morelog/1.log
c.log
d.log
```

I want to zip all of them.
As per example, they create entry and write data into it.

**Question**
- if I need to copy the data from eachfile like this, this would be inefficient, right?

How can I just give filepaths and tell it to create zip?

Comment: can't you put all the files into a single directory and zip that directory instead of zipping files seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For copying, have a look at [TFile.cp_rp(File)](https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TFile.html#cp_rp(java.io.File)).